# Is there any possible use for a recipe that I already know?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, oftentimes (especially during the current Wintersday event) you get recipes that you have already unlocked. Typically, I just sell them. I recently learned that runes and sigils that you don't need can be used in the Mystic Forge, so that makes me wonder: **Is there currently any use for unlocked recipes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Once they are unlocked on your characters crafting profession they are used. So selling them is really all you can do with them.

Comment: Slight correction: Recipes unlock by character rather than account, so you can still use them on other characters.

Comment: Yes true, by crafting profession per character. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Most recipes are not soulbound, so you can either:

- Sell on Trading Post
- Announce a giveaway on the Guild

Assuming that you already have a certain recipe, on a specific character, you can't "re-learn" it, so double-clicking it again won't work. There are new recipes once in a while (like the ones you can loot from Silverwastes), which makes it "harder" for newer players to catch-up with the releases. This is why I usually announce on Guild before selling it (mainly because 99% of the recipes will worth a few copper only, so why not give away?)